# How do I close a named file descriptor without closing stdin/stdout?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, file-descriptors

```
exec {ec}< <(echo "puts 'hello'") && sudo ruby /proc/$$/fd/${ec}
```

As soon as I close it with

```
exec <&"${ec}"-
```

The shell exits.

In another situation, I create this file descriptor:

```
exec {gr}> >(/usr/bin/grep 'hello')
```

Then I close it `exec >&${gr}-`, and now when I run a simple command like `ls`, nothing is printed.

I can do `ls >&2` and sure enough it shows something, but clearly stdout is now MIA.

---

I'm still learning how all this file descriptor business works, and would like some guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Bash's manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#:%7E:text=If%20%3E%26-%20or%20%3C%26-%20is%20preceded%20by%20%7Bvarname%7D%2C%20the%20value%20of%20varname%20defines%20the%20file%20descriptor%20to%20close.):

> If `>&-` or `<&-` is preceded by `{varname}`, the value of *varname* defines the file descriptor  to close.

So, it's `exec {fd}>&-` (or `{fd}<&-`) to close it.

```
$ exec {fd}>foo.out
$ echo "$fd"
10
$ echo hi >&"$fd"             # works
$ exec {fd}>&-                # close it
$ echo ho >&"$fd"             # doesn't work any more
bash: "$fd": Bad file descriptor
$ cat foo.out
hi
```

`exec <&"${ec}"-` moves the fd named in `$ec` to stdin (i.e. makes stdin a copy of fd `$ec`, then closes fd `$ec`). The shell now has its stdin connected to the process substitution, and continues reading input from there. But `ruby` probably already read everything, and the pipe would just give an EOF, exiting the shell.

Similarly, `exec >&${gr}-` redirects stdout to the fd stored in `$gr` (closing `$gr`). Any further regular output, like that from `ls` goes to the process substitution and the `grep`. So, `ls` might not produce any visible output, but `echo hello` should.

Though as usual, `$gr` here should be also quoted to avoid word splitting, since in general, `IFS` can contain digits. So that would be better written as  `exec >&"${gr}"-`.

The fd number you want to modify comes first in the redirections, the default being stdin (`0`) for `<` and stdout (`1`) for `>`.

Comment: Yea the `sudo ruby <(echo "puts 'hello'")` doesn't work. It is from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15708786/2089675). The only way it worked was the way I had it in my question. I was going for a one-liner

Comment: So you're saying that if I do something like `exec 1>&7-`, bash will simply parse this to mean "close fd 1", and just ignores the `7` in there? But without the `-`, it means, redirect fd 1 to fd 7? Seems like quite the jump in reasoning, but I guess it makes sense

Comment: @smac89, oooh, right, it's `/proc/$$/fd/`, not `/proc/self/fd/`, so you're letting ruby "steal" the fd from the shell's fd list. That's... somewhat convoluted, but ok, I suppose it works.

Comment: @smac89 `1>&7` would mean to fd 1 a copy of fd 7. `1>&-` would close fd 1. I'm not at all sure what `1>&7-` should be. Oh, should have read the manual, it moves the fd from 7 to 1.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand a bit now. So in my case, I was actually just closing stdin and stdout, and not the fd I was actually trying to close

Comment: And..I just saw the other hidden easter egg. I was doing `exec ${ec}<&-`, instead of `exec {ec}<&-`. Man I need to take a break from this

Comment: @smac89, not quite that either. Let's take something similar to the first one. `exec {ec}< <(echo "echo bye")`. Say `ec` gets the number 9, just to pick one. Now, fd 9 is connected 
to the process substitution. Now, don't do anything else with `$ec`, just run the `exec <&$ec-`, same as `exec 1<&9-`. That says to move 9 to 1 (stdin), so now 1 is connected to the process substitution and 9 gets closed. Then the shell reads input from 1, now the process substitution. It reads `echo bye`, runs that, gets an end-of-file, and exits.

Comment: @smac89, in my Bash, `exec ${ec}<&-` gives an error (it doesn't recognize the `${ec}` as part of the redirection.) But yah, `{ec}<&-` to close `$ec`.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around `exec <&$ec-` and your explanation but I think you've answered my questions. I will just ask a new one later

Comment: Actually I just got it, so that's the same as say I want to redirect stdout to stderr, and I do `>&2`, then if I append `-` to that command, it is exactly what I was doing in my question with `exec >&${gr}-` which causes stdout to be closed. Makes sense because when I check `/dev/fd/` the original fd (`${gr}`) is still there. Whyy bash? Whyy??

Comment: No I lied, it's not there. When I do `exec >&${gr}-`, `$gr` is gone as well. Oh well

Comment: _"assuming $gr is not IFS-splitted as you forgot the quotes and bash still does split+glob in redirections"_  Fortunately, bash will detect any IFS splits here; when discussing the `word` following a redirection operator, the man page now adds "If it expands to more than one word, bash reports an error."  So no need for quotes; either the programmer got the $gr correct or it won't work in any case.  :-)

Comment: @TiStrga, yes, but the error doesn't help much in the sense of getting the job done: the redirection still fails. E.g. `f="foo bar.txt"; echo foo > $f` just gives the error and nothing gets written to a file (not to `foo bar.txt`, nor `foo` nor `bar.txt`). In the case of `exec`, it's worse since unless you check that `exec` succeeds, the script just continues with the output going to the wrong place.